# Python read .bin data and convert to string

Tags: python, encoding, binary, byte, decoding

I have multiple bin files, and I want to extract the data from them, but the results i'm getting are pretty weird.

For example, my first file does the following:

```py
path = 'D:\lut.bin'
with open(path, 'rb') as file: # b is important -> binary
    fileContent = file.read()
    print(fileContent)
```

Output:

```
xc7\xfb\x99\x0c\x8e\xf9~7\xb9a\xb1*\x06\xd2o\xb8\xb2 \x81\x8bg\xd2\xc6bE\r\xb9KL7\xa0\xa52\xa5\xd2\x17\x86(\xe9\x02\xbf\xeb\x8fDvk\xe7\x8d\x03\x872\x9fop\xbck\xe1\x94\x02\xdc\xef\x85I\t\xc8\x8d\xdfl\x90\xcf*\xb1\x02(\x16~)\xc7\xa2\x1f\xf6o\xdc\x1en\x84H\xf6%\xfaW/\xee\xbc\xdd^/\x9b\x9a\xe5\x99\xa2\xd7\xe4\x93U\xd4\xef$\xa5\x8aW\xf6\xc9\xb0T\xe3<\x147\xcc\x08}\xc8\x15J3v\n\x9d\x16\xa3\x8d\r\xa2\xc4\x15\xf13!\xa2\x01\x14\xef\xaf\x06\x83p\xa7Ot\x8cr\xdf\xef\xbe\x93\xc2D`y\\\xdb\x8a\x1c\\H\x9cE\xabF\xd6\xe1B\xdd\xbc\x8a\xdb\x06|\x05{!\xf0K25K0\xb9\xfe\xa6n\xd7-\xd1\xcb\xefQ\xd9w\x08{4\x13\xba8\x06\x00}S\xe4\xd8*\xe2\x81f\x8d\xc4P\xde\x88/\xa6q\x7fG\x99\xbd\xa84v\xcfS+\xc6\xc5#\x0ey\xd8\xcd\xf2!\xf8`1\x03k5\xb9\xee\xb3V\xc3">\xdd\xf4\x94\x1b\x83\xf9\xdbe\xfcw\xf4+O\xf4\xf1\xfc\xa2 \xc5\xccq\xd1\xc8dH\x00\xf7K|7\x87\xa8$\xb8\x92^\x90.\xffK\xbf\xf6\xcaHv9l\xa6\x0e\xd5"\xd6`>}f\xfc\xd1\x15\xd0\xf0\x89\xb7\x12\xdf\xc9\xdfn\x97\xc7O\xf8\x05)Ua|\xd6\xd5\x03P\xf3\xcd\x08 \xc6\xc7\xe2"\xae\x1fz\xb9\xbd\x99\x100\x9a\x8d\xeb\x89\xa3T\xa0\xc7S\xcc\xe4h\xbe\xf3R\xe9\x9d\xf4Y\xe91\xa4%\x85>mn\xc3\x1e\x8a}\x04\xd9:\xb5\xde\x01h\x90y\xfe4&\xea\x1d\x9a\xbd\xac\x1a\x8e{\xb2Y\xcb\xc47\xd8\xe2\xf6\xd6\xdc\x91,]\x1d\xca\x90_sb\x86X\xad]\x8e\xe1A\x1a\xaa\xc6\xdf\x1ca@A\x1a\xa2\t!3\x06y\x92\x96\xebg\xdb3\xdd\x9f\xefh\x9d6\x17c0\x0e\xfe\x9a\x06\x06;\x16\xa7\x
```

I have no idea what this is, but it does not look like readable text, is there a way to even convert this?
My other file looks like this:

```
U\xff\xf3\xe8d\x00\x00\x00\x01\xa4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03H\x00\x00\x00\x00LAME3.100UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
```

Again with the same code above.

I have tried decoding it, I keep getting decoding errors, and text encoding to `utf-8` doesn't help either.

I want to get the text from this, these files came with book on the playstore I downloaded.

Comment: Could you explain what kind of information you want to extract from those files?

Comment: where did these files come from, i.e. what program produced them / do you have specifications for the format?

Comment: I want to extract the text from those files, I don't know what program produced them I had found them on my phone after downloading an app that is a book, I assume that the text from that book would be in those `.bin` files and I would want to extract it if its possible.
Also the output I get is really long, I only posted a small snippet of it.

Comment: Please show us decoding errors and what result you are expecting - if that is just bin data, then it doesn't have to be convertable to text - and it isn't, because Python visualise those even in byte streams: see your prints, all `\xNN` where N is hex digit are hex codes that don't correspond to printable characters, and e.g. beginning U and ending UUUUU... are in fact `'\x55'` - print `'\x55'` and see for yourself!

Comment: @h4z3 The decoding errors only appeared when I tried to use `encoding='utf-8'` or other things like that with my code above it didn't give errors anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Bin files are just binary data, meaning each byte can be any value between 0 and 255 (`00000000` and `11111111`, hex `0x00`-`0xFF`).

Printable characters are a subset of those codes.

This means, not every bin file can be converted to text.

---

Python tries to visualise the byte stream already by putting those printable characters in place of their `\xNN` code (where N is a hex digit). The rest of the characters are printed as their codes.

This means the

```
U\xff\xf3\xe8d\x00\x00\x00\x01\xa4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03H\x00\x00\x00\x00LAME3.100UU
```

is in fact

```
\x55\xff\xf3\xe8\x64\x00\x00\x00\x01\xa4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x48\x00\x00\x00\x00\x4c\x41\x4d\x45\x33\x2e\x31\x30\x30\x55\x55
```

[Copy this into your Python interpreter as a string (i.e. in quotes) and see how it visually converts itself when displaying/printing!]

The parts:

- decoded `U`,
- then not decoded `\xff\xf3\xe8`
- decoded `d`
- not decoded `\x00\x00\x00\x01\xa4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03`
- decoded`H`
- not decoded `\x00\x00\x00\x00`
- decoded `LAME3.100UU`

Can you extract some data from it? Depending on the type of the bin, you may probably find **some** strings directly put in there - like the `LAME3.10` that looks like some code/version... but **I really doubt that you would find anything useful. It can be literally anything, just dumped there: text, photo, memory dump...**

Comment: This is super insightful on byte data and stuff, thank you for this. I have tried extracting some data, but I keep getting `this file is corrupted` or something along those lines.
My steps I took to try and extract data are:
1) convert `.bin` to `.iso` which was succesful.
2) trying to extract the data or anything from the `.iso` led me to corruption errors. Thus I could no get any actual data extracted from it. The conversion process did say that there were no errors in the process of converting, but I'm not sure how to go about extracting, I will keep trying.

Comment: "converting" in this case is basically changing the extension and hoping reading data as if it was structured will succeed - it won't. Structured means the data is ordered in some way that some codec will recognise - most often it's marked by a header (a few beginning or near-beginning bytes) like described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: `LAME` is an encoding for `.mp3` files of somesort, so I assume that those bytes in that data is an audio file and not text?

Comment: As I said: it could be literally anything. You can try to read it as mp3, maybe it will yield something useful but you have to know it can yield nothing. - It can be some weird format, or it can be just a dump readable by that program.

Comment: I asked the developer about those `.bin` files and they stated that they are just text.. but when ever I try and extract it with software it keeps giving me errors, about not correct format or other stuff. So I do believe that there is contents in there. But the main problem is getting it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is very late, but LAME3.100 followed by a bunch of U characters is actually the start of a certain encoding of .mp3 file, and knowing that it may possibly be incomplete, you could try and convert it using https://ffmpeg.org into a proper .mp3 container

After you have ffmpeg in your path, a command such as `ffmpeg -i "D:/lut.bin" "D:/lut.mp3"` should hopefully decode and re-encode it